# How to pass custom header to RESTful call?

Tags: php, rest, http-headers

There are some web service APIs that I need to connect to for my website. Most of the APIs involve something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.someservice.com/api/fetch?key=1234567890
```

But one web service requires the API key to be set in a custom HTTP header. How do I make the request to this API url and pass the custom header at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) like this:

```
<?php
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"CustomHeader: yay\r\n" .
              "AnotherHeader: test\r\n"
  )
);
$context=stream_context_create($options);
$data=file_get_contents('http://www.someservice.com/api/fetch?key=1234567890',false,$context);
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the best solution to the question; however it's probably worth mentioning curl as a fully-fledged alternative.

Comment: I was typing up the same answer til you posted yours so I provided a curl example instead.

Comment: I agree curl is a good alternative (and more useful in many cases) but I need to use `file_get_contents` in this situation. Good answer! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to redirect using this method? I am able to implement it but not able to redirect to "http://www.someservice.com/api/fetch?key=1234567890"

Answer (score 4):

You could use curl. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.someservice.com/api/fetch?key=1234567890');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Header: value'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'method' => 'GET',
'header' => 'CUSTOM HEADER HERE',
)
));

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: 42|W3hpHwxdYXSgOVRDsi7AD8Wg4pEKHebBey0AWpzH"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```